# How to retrieve time from Firebase TimeStamp[Flutter]?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I retrieve only time and date separately from Firebase in Flutter (Dart).

So far I had gone through many methods DateFormat,SubString and soon but nothing is suitable for TimeStamp class of flutter.

`timeStamp : October 19, 2020 at 6:33:13 PM UTC+5:30`

This is my timeStamp I need to get that 6:33:13 from it.

There is no specified method to get date or time from Firebase for TimeStamp in flutter may be.

Comment: Firestore timestamps don't have date and time manipulation methods.  You have to convert it to something else that does, such as a native Date object, using `toDate()`.  From there, you can use any tool you want that works with dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
final Timestamp timestamp = snapshot.data['timestamp'] as Timestamp;
final DateTime dateTime = timestamp.toDate();
final dateString = DateFormat('K:mm:ss').format(dateTime);
```